# Invalid configuration object in webpack.config.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack-2

I get contiously this error

Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.

my webpack.config.js is as this

```
var path    = require('path');
var hwp     = require('html-webpack-plugin');

  module.exports = {
entry: path.join(__dirname, '/src/index.js'),
output: {
    filename: 'build.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist')
},

module: {
    rules: [
        { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: ['ts-loader'] },
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/, use: [{
                loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS 
strings
            }, {
                loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
            }, {
                loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
            }]
        },
        { test: /\.(otf|ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/, 
 loader: 'file-loader?name=./Scripts/dist/[name].[ext]' }
    ]
},
plugins:[
    new hwp({template:path.join(__dirname, '/src/index.html')})
]
}
```

can somebody help me, I have tried many samples of webpack.config.js but they don't work. is it really so hard to work with react?
I am new in react. I know how to code, but I can not build a project of my own

Comment: have you used [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)?  It is designed to eliminate complicated configuration.

Comment: yes. I used it . but I tried as a beginner to  make it myself from scratch. it works but  without using it, I was not successful. Thank you

Comment: If you are new to react, why are you trying to do this? If you want to learn how to 'make it from scratch', I suggest reading the source for `react-scripts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following snippet:

```
var path = require("path");
var hwp = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, "/src/index.js"),
  output: {
    filename: "build.js",
    path: path.join(__dirname, "/dist")
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: ["ts-loader"] },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(otf|ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
        loader: "file-loader?name=./Scripts/dist/[name].[ext]"
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new hwp({ template: path.join(__dirname, "/src/index.html") })]
};
```

Comment: thank you . I tried it and it didn't work. I should try all my code again. maybe there is a mistake somewhere else, because I have tried too many codes. no of them works!!

Comment: i tried to make a new simple project, following the steps in this link

(https://codeburst.io/setting-up-a-react-project-from-scratch-d62f38ab6d97)

but still continuously the same problem

Comment: it doesn't work yet. but now  the  Error is something new. at last i am relieved from the last error. but I think the new error is not about webpack.config but something else. it is

You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

I should try to know what is the reason for this new error.

thank you very much for your kindness.